# where can i get that saveShippingMethod in Js

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, paypal-express

where can i get that save Shipping Method i am on order review page while making payment via pay pal i am not able to find that method . i am getting the below response on my console

POST XHR  http://www.testdomain.com/paypal/express/saveShippingMethod/

Response :
isAjaxtrue
shipping_method freeshipping_freeshipping

Answer (score 0):

**I found it myself after spend couple of hours hope this will help someone in future**

`skin\frontend\base\default\js\checkout\review.js`

```
  _submitShipping : function(event, url, resultId)
    {
       // $j = jQuery;
        if (this.shippingSelect && url && resultId) {
            this._updateOrderSubmit(true);
            if (this._pleaseWait) {
                this._pleaseWait.show();
            }
            if ('' != this.shippingSelect.value) {
               // alert(this.shippingSelect.value);

                    new Ajax.Updater(resultId, url, {
                    parameters: {isAjax:true, shipping_method:this.shippingSelect.value},
                    onComplete: function() {
                        if (this._pleaseWait) {
                            this._pleaseWait.hide();
                        }
                    }.bind(this),
                    onSuccess: this._onSubmitShippingSuccess.bind(this),
                    evalScripts: true
                });
            }
        }
    },
```